# Is this a black carpet beetle and how do I keep it alive?

Tags: entomology

[image: Side view]

[image: Top view]

[image: Under side]

About 3mm in length, location Hong Kong. Is it possible to keep it as a pet? I currently have it in a clear plastic case (kinda cubic, 6.5cm per side) with a piece of moist paper. It rarely flies.